# I have to draw square inside of square in c++

Tags: c++, loops, drawing

I have task to draw square inside of square inside of square etc. It looks like this. For number 10 inputed, we have to draw:

```
**********
*        *
* ****** *
* *    * *
* * ** * *
* * ** * *
* *    * *
* ****** *
*        *   
**********
```

I managed to code this:

```
int n;
std::cin>>n;


for(int i=0;i<n;i++) 
   std::cout<<"*";

std::cout<<std::endl <<"*";

for(int i=0;i<n-2;i++) 
    std::cout<<" ";

std::cout<<"*"<<std::endl <<"*";

for(int i=0;i<n-2;i++)
   std::cout<<" ";

std::cout<<"*"<<std::endl;

for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    std::cout<<"*";

std::cout<<std::endl;

return 0;
}
```

, and I have to use some connection between repetition of blank spaces and "*", and I know i have to use mathematical expresion and bool's algebra> I just need an hint not to solve me this problem. Should i try to split this shape in 4 or 2 parts(biggest problem is this smallest square or blank space. It repeat for even and odd numbers, but for even smoetimes it's balnk space, somethimes its little square. I hope that you understand my english, and hope that some kind of hint or help will come...:D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>    // for std::min()

int dist (int dim, int r, int c)
{
    return std::min(std::min(r, dim-1-r), std::min(c, dim-1-c));
}

char char_at_point (int dim, int r, int c)
{
    if ((dist(dim, r, c) % 2) == 0) return '*';
    else return ' ';
}

int main() {
    int dim = 0;
    std::cin >> dim;

    for (int r = 0; r < dim; ++r)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < dim; ++c)
            std::cout << char_at_point(dim, r, c);
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Basically, the easiest way to do something like this is have a function (in mathematical sense) that tells you whether you need to fill a point at a certain coordinate or not. If you had that function, you'd just loop over the coordinates of the whole square and use that function to decide whether to print an asterisk there or a space character.

That function, in your case is pretty straightforward to build; you can determine the distance of each point from the perimeter of the outermost square and fill that coordinate if and only if the distance is divisible by two.

Comment: @Bosancheros, if this answer helped you, I think, it would be appropriate to accept it (or at least upvote it. Or both). Otherwise, I guess, you should clarify why you don't want to do it (how can this answer be improved).